# Impresion de tickets C#

Tags: c#, impresión, código-de-barras

Buenas noches:

Quisiera pedir ayuda con un programa que imprime tickets de venta, tengo hecha toda la impresión de tickets pero necesito agregar una imagen de cabecera y un código de barras al final y no se como hacerlo :(, espero me puedan ayudar dejo el código para que lo revisen y por si a alguien le sirve.

Código clase CrearTicket

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace sistema_compu
{
    class CrearTicket
    {
        StringBuilder linea = new StringBuilder();
        private Image headerImage = null;
        //Creamos una variable para almacenar el numero maximo de caracteres que permitiremos en el ticket.
        int maxCar = 48, cortar;//Para una impresora ticketera que imprime a 40 columnas. La variable cortar cortara el texto cuando rebase el limte.

        public Image HeaderImage
        {
            get { return headerImage; }
            set { if (headerImage != value) headerImage = value; }
        }

        //Creamos el primer metodo, este dibujara lineas guion.
        public string lineasGuio()
        {
            string lineasGuion = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < maxCar; i++)
            {
                lineasGuion += "-";//Agregara un guio hasta llegar la numero maximo de caracteres.
            }
            return linea.AppendLine(lineasGuion).ToString(); //Devolvemos la lineaGuion
        }

        //Metodo para dibujar una linea con asteriscos
        public string lineasAsteriscos()
        {
            string lineasAsterisco = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < maxCar; i++)
            {
                lineasAsterisco += "*";//Agregara un asterisco hasta llegar la numero maximo de caracteres.
            }
            return linea.AppendLine(lineasAsterisco).ToString(); //Devolvemos la linea con asteriscos
        }

        //Realizamos el mismo procedimiento para dibujar una lineas con el signo igual
        public string lineasIgual()
        {
            string lineasIgual = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < maxCar; i++)
            {
                 lineasIgual += "=";//Agregara un igual hasta llegar la numero maximo de caracteres.
            }
            return linea.AppendLine(lineasIgual).ToString(); //Devolvemos la lienas con iguales
        }

        //Creamos un metodo para poner el texto a la izquierda
        public void TextoIzquierda(string texto)
        {
            //Si la longitud del texto es mayor al numero maximo de caracteres permitidos, realizar el siguiente procedimiento.
            if (texto.Length > maxCar)
            {
                int caracterActual = 0;//Nos indicara en que caracter se quedo al bajar el texto a la siguiente linea
                for (int longitudTexto = texto.Length; longitudTexto > maxCar; longitudTexto -= maxCar)
                {
                    //Agregamos los fragmentos que salgan del texto
                    linea.AppendLine(texto.Substring(caracterActual, maxCar));
                    caracterActual += maxCar;
                }
                //agregamos el fragmento restante
                linea.AppendLine(texto.Substring(caracterActual, texto.Length - caracterActual));
            }
            else
            {
                //Si no es mayor solo agregarlo.
                linea.AppendLine(texto);
            }
        }

        //Creamos un metodo para poner texto a la derecha.
        public void TextoDerecha(string texto)
        {
            //Si la longitud del texto es mayor al numero maximo de caracteres permitidos, realizar el siguiente procedimiento.
            if (texto.Length > maxCar)
            {
                int caracterActual = 0;//Nos indicara en que caracter se quedo al bajar el texto a la siguiente linea
                for (int longitudTexto = texto.Length; longitudTexto > maxCar; longitudTexto -= maxCar)
                {
                    //Agregamos los fragmentos que salgan del texto
                    linea.AppendLine(texto.Substring(caracterActual, maxCar));
                    caracterActual += maxCar;
                }
                //Variable para poner espacios restntes
                string espacios = "";
                //Obtenemos la longitud del texto restante.
                for (int i = 0; i < (maxCar - texto.Substring(caracterActual, texto.Length - caracterActual).Length); i++)
                {
                    espacios += " ";//Agrega espacios para alinear a la derecha
                }

                //agregamos el fragmento restante, agregamos antes del texto los espacios
                linea.AppendLine(espacios + texto.Substring(caracterActual, texto.Length - caracterActual));
            }
            else
            {
                string espacios = "";
                //Obtenemos la longitud del texto restante.
                for (int i = 0; i < (maxCar - texto.Length); i++)
                {
                    espacios += " ";//Agrega espacios para alinear a la derecha
                }
                //Si no es mayor solo agregarlo.
                linea.AppendLine(espacios + texto);
            }
        }

        //Metodo para centrar el texto
        public void TextoCentro(string texto)
        {
            if (texto.Length > maxCar)
            {
                int caracterActual = 0;//Nos indicara en que caracter se quedo al bajar el texto a la siguiente linea
                for (int longitudTexto = texto.Length; longitudTexto > maxCar; longitudTexto -= maxCar)
                {
                    //Agregamos los fragmentos que salgan del texto
                    linea.AppendLine(texto.Substring(caracterActual, maxCar));
                    caracterActual += maxCar;
                }
                //Variable para poner espacios restntes
                string espacios = "";
                //sacamos la cantidad de espacios libres y el resultado lo dividimos entre dos
                int centrar = (maxCar - texto.Substring(caracterActual, texto.Length - caracterActual).Length) / 2;
            //Obtenemos la longitud del texto restante.
            for (int i = 0; i < centrar; i++)
            {
                espacios += " ";//Agrega espacios para centrar
            }

            //agregamos el fragmento restante, agregamos antes del texto los espacios
            linea.AppendLine(espacios + texto.Substring(caracterActual, texto.Length - caracterActual));
            }
            else
            {
                string espacios = "";
                //sacamos la cantidad de espacios libres y el resultado lo dividimos entre dos
                int centrar = (maxCar - texto.Length) / 2;
                //Obtenemos la longitud del texto restante.
                for (int i = 0; i < centrar; i++)
                {
                    espacios += " ";//Agrega espacios para centrar
                }

                //agregamos el fragmento restante, agregamos antes del texto los espacios
                linea.AppendLine(espacios + texto);

            }
        }

        //Metodo para poner texto a los extremos
        public void TextoExtremos(string textoIzquierdo, string textoDerecho)
        {
            //variables que utilizaremos
            string textoIzq, textoDer, textoCompleto = "", espacios = "";

            //Si el texto que va a la izquierda es mayor a 18, cortamos el texto.
            if (textoIzquierdo.Length > 22)
            {
                cortar = textoIzquierdo.Length - 22;
                textoIzq = textoIzquierdo.Remove(22, cortar);
            }
            else
            { textoIzq = textoIzquierdo; }

            textoCompleto = textoIzq;//Agregamos el primer texto.

            if (textoDerecho.Length > 24)//Si es mayor a 20 lo cortamos
            {
                cortar = textoDerecho.Length - 24;
                textoDer = textoDerecho.Remove(24, cortar);
            }
            else
            { textoDer = textoDerecho; }

            //Obtenemos el numero de espacios restantes para poner textoDerecho al final
            int nroEspacios = maxCar - (textoIzq.Length + textoDer.Length);
            for (int i = 0; i < nroEspacios; i++)
            {
                espacios += " ";//agrega los espacios para poner textoDerecho al final
            }
            textoCompleto += espacios + textoDerecho;//Agregamos el segundo texto con los espacios para alinearlo a la derecha.
            linea.AppendLine(textoCompleto);//agregamos la linea al ticket, al objeto en si.
        }

        //Creamos el encabezado para los articulos
        public void EncabezadoVenta()
        {
            //Escribimos los espacios para mostrar el articulo. En total tienen que ser 40 caracteres
            linea.AppendLine("ITEM                          |CANT  |PRECIO    ");
        }

        //Metodo para agregar los totales d ela venta
        public void AgregarTotales(string texto, decimal total)
        {
            //Variables que usaremos
            string resumen, valor, textoCompleto, espacios = "";

            if (texto.Length > 29)//Si es mayor a 25 lo cortamos
            {
                cortar = texto.Length - 29;
                resumen = texto.Remove(29, cortar);
            }
            else
            { resumen = texto; }

            textoCompleto = resumen;
            valor = total.ToString("#,#.00");//Agregamos el total previo formateo.

            //Obtenemos el numero de espacios restantes para alinearlos a la derecha
            int nroEspacios = maxCar - (resumen.Length + valor.Length);
            //agregamos los espacios
            for (int i = 0; i < nroEspacios; i++)
            {
                espacios += " ";
            }
            textoCompleto += espacios + valor;
            linea.AppendLine(textoCompleto);
        }

        //Metodo para agreagar articulos al ticket de venta
        public void AgregaArticulo(string articulo, int cant, decimal precio)
        {
            //Valida que cant precio e importe esten dentro del rango.
            if (cant.ToString().Length <= 7 && precio.ToString().Length <= 11)
            {
                string elemento = "", espacios = "";
                bool bandera = false;//Indicara si es la primera linea que se escribe cuando bajemos a la segunda si el nombre del articulo no entra en la primera linea
                int nroEspacios = 0;

                //Si el nombre o descripcion del articulo es mayor a 20, bajar a la siguiente linea
                if (articulo.Length > 24)
                {
                    //Colocar la cantidad a la derecha.
                    nroEspacios = (7 - cant.ToString().Length);
                    espacios = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < nroEspacios; i++)
                    {
                        espacios += " ";//Generamos los espacios necesarios para alinear a la derecha
                    }
                    elemento += espacios + cant.ToString();//agregamos la cantidad con los espacios

                    //Colocar el precio a la derecha.
                    nroEspacios = (11 - precio.ToString().Length);
                    espacios = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < nroEspacios; i++)
                    {
                        espacios += " ";//Genera los espacios
                    }
                    //el operador += indica que agregar mas cadenas a lo que ya existe.
                    elemento += espacios + precio.ToString();//Agregamos el precio a la variable elemento

                    int caracterActual = 0;//Indicara en que caracter se quedo al bajae a la siguiente linea

                    //Por cada 20 caracteres se agregara una linea siguiente
                    for (int longitudTexto = articulo.Length; longitudTexto > 24; longitudTexto -= 24)
                    {
                        if (bandera == false)//si es false o la primera linea en recorrerer, continuar...
                        {
                            //agregamos los primeros 20 caracteres del nombre del articulos, mas lo que ya tiene la variable elemento
                            linea.AppendLine(articulo.Substring(caracterActual, 24) + elemento);
                            bandera = true;//cambiamos su valor a verdadero
                        }
                        else
                            linea.AppendLine(articulo.Substring(caracterActual, 24));//Solo agrega el nombre del articulo

                        caracterActual += 24;//incrementa en 20 el valor de la variable caracterActual
                    }
                    //Agrega el resto del fragmento del  nombre del articulo
                    linea.AppendLine(articulo.Substring(caracterActual, articulo.Length - caracterActual));

                }
                else //Si no es mayor solo agregarlo, sin dar saltos de lineas
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < (24 - articulo.Length); i++)
                    {
                        espacios += " "; //Agrega espacios para completar los 20 caracteres
                    }
                    elemento = articulo + espacios;

                    //Colocar la cantidad a la derecha.
                    nroEspacios = (7 - cant.ToString().Length);// +(20 - elemento.Length);
                    espacios = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < nroEspacios; i++)
                    {
                        espacios += " ";
                    }
                    elemento += espacios + cant.ToString();

                    //Colocar el precio a la derecha.
                    nroEspacios = (11 - precio.ToString().Length);
                    espacios = "";
                    for (int i = 0; i < nroEspacios; i++)
                    {
                        espacios += " ";
                    }
                    elemento += espacios + precio.ToString();

                    linea.AppendLine(elemento);//Agregamos todo el elemento: nombre del articulo, cant, precio, importe.
                }
            }
            else
            {
                linea.AppendLine("Los valores ingresados para esta fila");
                linea.AppendLine("superan las columnas soportdas por éste.");
                throw new Exception("Los valores ingresados para algunas filas del ticket\nsuperan las columnas soportdas por éste.");
            }
        }

        //Metodos para enviar secuencias de escape a la impresora
        //Para cortar el ticket
        public void CortaTicket()
        {
            linea.AppendLine("\x1B" + "m"); //Caracteres de corte. Estos comando varian segun el tipo de impresora
            linea.AppendLine("\x1B" + "d" + "\x00"); //Avanza 9 renglones, Tambien varian
        }

        //Para abrir el cajon
        public void AbreCajon()
        {
            //Estos tambien varian, tienen que ever el manual de la impresora para poner los correctos.
            linea.AppendLine("\x1B" + "p" + "\x00" + "\x0F" + "\x96"); //Caracteres de apertura cajon 0
            //linea.AppendLine("\x1B" + "p" + "\x01" + "\x0F" + "\x96"); //Caracteres de apertura cajon 1
        }

        //Para mandara a imprimir el texto a la impresora que le indiquemos.
        public void ImprimirTicket(string impresora)
        {
            //Este metodo recibe el nombre de la impresora a la cual se mandara a imprimir y el texto que se imprimira.
            //Usaremos un código que nos proporciona Microsoft. https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/kb/322091

            RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(impresora, linea.ToString()); //Imprime texto.
            //linea.Clear();//Al cabar de imprimir limpia la linea de todo el texto agregado.
        }
    }

    //Clase para mandara a imprimir texto plano a la impresora
    public class RawPrinterHelper
    {
        // Structure and API declarions:
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public class DOCINFOA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDocName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pOutputFile;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDataType;
        }
        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

        // SendBytesToPrinter()
        // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
        // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
        // Returns true on success, false on failure.
        public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
        {
            Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
            IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
            DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
            bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

            di.pDocName = "Ticket de Venta";//Este es el nombre con el que guarda el archivo en caso de no imprimir a la impresora fisica.
            di.pDataType = "RAW";//de tipo texto plano
            //di.pOutputFile = "D:\\ticket.txt";

            // Open the printer.
            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                // Start a document.
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    // Start a page.
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        // Write your bytes.
                        bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }
                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
            // about why not.
            if (bSuccess == false)
            {
                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            return bSuccess;
        }

        public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
        {
            IntPtr pBytes;
            Int32 dwCount;
            // How many characters are in the string?
            dwCount = szString.Length;
            // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
            // the string to ANSI text.
            pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
            // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
            SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Código botón que imprime

```
private void btnImprimir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        CrearTicket ticket = new CrearTicket();

        ticket.TextoIzquierda(" ");
        ticket.TextoCentro("TICKET CIERRE DE CAJA");
        ticket.TextoIzquierda(" ");
        ticket.TextoExtremos("FECHA : " + txtFecha.Text, "HORA : " + txtHora.Text);
        ticket.TextoIzquierda(" ");
        ticket.EncabezadoVenta();
        ticket.lineasGuio();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow fila in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            ticket.AgregaArticulo(fila.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), int.Parse(fila.Cells[0].Value.ToString()), decimal.Parse(fila.Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
        }
        ticket.lineasIgual();
        ticket.AgregarTotales("          TOTAL COMPRADO : $ ", decimal.Parse(txtCompra.Text));
        ticket.AgregarTotales("          TOTAL VENDIDO  : $ ", decimal.Parse(txtVenta.Text));
        ticket.TextoIzquierda(" ");
        ticket.AgregarTotales("          GANANCIA       : $ ", decimal.Parse(txtResultado.Text));
        ticket.TextoIzquierda(" ");
        ticket.TextoIzquierda(" ");
        ticket.TextoIzquierda(" ");
        ticket.TextoIzquierda(" ");
        ticket.TextoIzquierda(" ");
        ticket.TextoIzquierda(" ");
        ticket.CortaTicket();
        ticket.ImprimirTicket("EPSON TM-T20II Receipt");
    }
    catch (Exception eeee) { }
}
```

Comment: Aunque no lo especificas, imagino que se trata de una impresora termica de tickets. Si es asi,para hacer lo que quieres debes consultar la documentación de la impresora que estás utilizando. Creo recordar que para imprimir una imagen de cabecera debes almacenarla en una zona de la memoria de la propia impresora. En cuanto a los códigos de barras, tambien suelen venir preparadas con un juego de caracteres especiales para codigo de barras.

Comment: Lograste resolver el problema?

Answer (score 1):

La forma que estás utilizando, imprime línea por línea como texto plano en la impresora, por lo que no puedes dar texto enriquecido y mucho menos imágenes, aunque sí te permite tener control sobre secuencias de escape que permitan abrir una gaveta o cortar papel.

En otras palabras, no se puede de esa forma, te recomiendo usar rdlc o crystal reports.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

No se si ya hayas encontrado la solución, pero si analizas el código la respuesta esta al principio aquí:

```
public Image HeaderImage
{
    get { return headerImage; }
    set { if (headerImage != value) headerImage = value; }
}
```

para poner una imagen de cabecera lo usarías así:

```
ticket.HeaderImage= picturebox1.image;
```